# A doubt in special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics

I read in the Feynman Lecs about muons.

They are created in the upper atmosphere and hav a lifespan of about 2.2 micro seconds and if there was no relativity, they can travel as much as 600 metres only.But, they reach our labs (we detected them) and have thus travelled about 10 km.

My doubt is: Do the muons, after they are created , do they measure their own speeds to have a value, which makes them think that it is obvious that they should reach as far down the atmosphere as to the labs or are they surprised with the fact that they reach the labs? (maybe they were expecting to become disintegrated at the ....stratosphere maybe?)

**EDIT: To all downvoters:** please feel free to replace the muon with a space ship with a 2.2 microsecond lifetime after which it will get disintegrated completely. Will the people inside predict that they would go as far as the stratosphere(say) or will they know that they would come as far down as the labs?

Comment: You seem to think that muons have a mind of their own and decide what "they" should be doing? Muons, like all other objects in the universe simply follow some laws of physics.

Comment: @Prahar Why did you downvote?

Comment: @SamamaFahim - It wasn't me that downvoted.

Comment: @Prahar Please feel free to change the muon into a space ship that is will get completely vapourised in 2.2 microseconds because of matter-anti matter interactions. I really dont understand why this has been down voted.

Comment: What do you mean "measure their own speed"? In *their frame*, they are *by definition at rest*.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I did not know that. So, if it was replace by the space ship in the previous comment, what then?

Comment: @Prahar why did you downvote 3rd time?

Comment: @Prahar What is going on here?

Comment: Uh...nothing changes for the spaceship. I don't understand what your actual question is - from our perspective, the muons survive until the ground because of time dilation, from their own perspective, the muon survive until the ground because of length contraction - in their frame, the way to the ground is not nearly as long.

Comment: @Sidarth - Firstly, you can only downvote once. Secondly, as I have previously mentioned, I am not the one downvoting this question.

Comment: From a logical perspective you have to keep in mind that the muons' velocity depends on the observer. The muons couldn't measure it, "even if they wanted to" because there is not one velocity but infinitely many of them. The logical consistency between these infinitely many observers admits only two different physically relevant solutions, one is Galilean invariance, the other is Lorentz invariance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From our perspective, the muons survive because time dilation increases their lifespan in our frame compared to their rest frame.

From their own perspective, the muons survive because length contraction shortens the distance to the ground to a distance they can cover in their lifetime.

Comment: This film (not video, film!) explains it best...http://www.scivee.tv/node/2415